# AWS Route53 pointing to a elastic beanstalk webapp

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I've got a web applicaiton set up on elastic beanstalk. I've a domain on route53, and I've followed the guides more or less here:
[http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBJEc.png)

The URL to the webapp works fine, but the DNS is not pointing me to it.
To be honest, I'm not sure where to even begin looking at how to fix this. I've tried to use the 'Check response from Route 53' feature and I can't see anything out of the ordinary. I've attached a lot of pics.

Any idea?

Please see here for the images, I couldn't upload them here. I kepy getting format errors.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F79G0.jpg

******update*******

Updated, new hosted zone configuration:
[image]

******update*******

The name is still not resolving. I've added an A type record set and selected the elastic beanstlak as the alais.

[image]

******Answer*******

Credit to imperalix for this.

Amazon registered the wrong name servers for my site.
I needed to go to

https://www.whois.net/

and search for my www.thetellyourstory.com

I got the values for my name server there:
Name Server: NS-1487.AWSDNS-57.ORG
Name Server: NS-187.AWSDNS-23.COM
Name Server: NS-1891.AWSDNS-44.CO.UK
Name Server: NS-802.AWSDNS-36.NET

Then, go into route 53 and update the name server values:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html

It's important to update the name server values only as above. You can edit them directly from *https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v28T.jpg* here but it does not update the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your registrar, Amazon, has the wrong name servers configured [1].  I compared your whois information with your screenshot.  I would recommend updating your name servers[2] for your domain to match what your zone has configured.

Update your registrar to (this is from your screenshot of Route 53 DNS):

- ns-1487.awsdns-57.org.
- ns-187.awsdns-23.com.
- ns-1891.awsdns-44.co.uk.
- ns-802.awsdns-36.net.

Your Route 53 DNS configuration look fine[3].

1. $ whois thetellyourstory.com
2. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html
3. http://digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=www.thetellyourstory.com.&type=&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=self&nameservers=ns-187.awsdns-23.com

Comment: Thanks for the help Imprealix. I've updated my question with some screen shots and will update tomorrow.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the name servers you should set for your domain.  I got this information from your Route 53 DNS screen shot.

Comment: I updated my route 53 name servers back to what you suggested. The last image in post is now the values I have in my name servers. How long do you think I need to wait more or less before my registrar is updated?

Comment: WHOIS should be pretty quick.  Then it's just waiting for caches to expire.  Are you sure you updated Amazon Registrar?  I still show last updated Date: 23-sep-2016.

Comment: Hey man, yeah, I updated it yesterday. I've uploaded a screen shot here: http://imgur.com/a/a41z2 . But, when I followed your link [2], it still showed the old values. Not sure why but amazon never updated the values when I edited them on a different screen. http://imgur.com/a/uZilz  I've updated them now. I appreciate the help

Comment: Hey man, that fixed it. Thanks. i'll update my comment and mark this as the answer. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

- Change the NS record to just `tellyourstory.com`, i.e. remove the "www." from the name value.
- Delete the CNAME record with the name `cname.www.tellyourstory.com`
- Change the A record `www.tellyourstory.com` to a CNAME record. This record doesn't need to be an alias. It just needs to have the value of your elastic beanstalk app.

How long ago did you register this domain name and create these records? For a new domain name it can take 24 hours or so for DNS records to start resolving.

Comment: Hi Mark, I registered the name last week sometime. I've made those changes and saved it. i'll wait a few hours to see does it take affect. I've edit my question above to reflect your changes and added a screen shot of my hosted zones. Fingers crossed. Thank for the help.